# Play bxSlider on element hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, bxslider

I have a wordpress loop loading multiple bxsliders onto one page, i want these sliders to start individually and stop individually on hover of the parent element. I can't figure out how to do so.

Obviously i will need to use a

```
$('.item').each
```

But im not sure how to stop and start the bxslider on the hover. Does anyone have a solution?

Here is some sample code:

```
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
            ?>
                <div class="item">
                            <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if Thumbnail exists ?>
                                        <h1 title="<?php the_title(); ?>" >
                                            <a href="<?php the_field('website_url'); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                                        </h1>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div>
                                        <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image'); endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div>
                                        <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'third-image'); endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                             </div>
                     </div> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

So you can see there im, pulling 3 thumbnails out... in the slider  and this is within a post so there could be anywhere between 1 and 10 on the page.

My first idea was to initiate the bxslider on hover....

```
    $('.item').each(function(){
    $(this).hover({
        $(this).find('.thumbnail ul').bxSlider({
            auto: true
        });
    });
});
```

But this doesn't work. How i want it to, i want it to build the slider on each one... then when the user hovers make the slider start... and on mouse off stop.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Pleas, provide a sample code or a demo on jsfiddle

Comment: Have updated with more of code im using. Not sure i can use fiddle as its running in wordpress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look through bxSlider API methods **[here](http://bxslider.com/options)**:

The solution is to use `.startAuto();` and `.stopAuto();`:

```
$('.bxSlider').each(function() {
    var _this = $(this).bxSlider({
        auto: false,
        speed: 200,
        pause: 500
    });
    _this.mouseenter(function() {   
         _this.startAuto();      
     }).mouseleave(function() {   
         _this.stopAuto();
    });
});
```

**Example:**  http://jsfiddle.net/verber/KBfx9/28/

For relating the event to sliders parent use this one:

```
     $('.yourParentParent').mouseenter(function() {   
         _this.startAuto();      
     }).mouseleave(function() {   
         _this.stopAuto();
     });
```

If you do not want the initiation for all the sliders on the page, change `_this` to your exact bxSlider selector.

Comment: I looked into this but every time i tried to call .startAuto i got a console error, not sure why. But what you have given me there is spot on thanks. How would i aim to trigger the startAuto on the parents parent? for example 2 up instead of itself?